# API doesn't return 'body_markdown' on comment endpoint

Tags: bug, api

I am using the following filter: `!1zSk*x-OuqdUnozJsdd2S`

This should return the default items in `wrapper` and `body_markdown`, `comment_id`, `link` and `post_id` in the `comment` section.

The `body_markdown` doesn't appear.

However, if I use `body` instead of `body_markdown`, I *do* receive the HTML encoded version of the comment text.

URL to API Example where it doesn't work (returning the 100 more recent comments on Stack Overflow). I've make it a code block, because the asterisk breaks the URL parsing.

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/comments#pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&filter=!1zSk*x-OuqdUnozJsdd2S&site=stackoverflow&run=true
```